# How do I make the window canvas transparent in tkinter, but the elements not?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a cursortrail overlay, where the window displays a trail behind the cursor to make it look smoother, and the background of the window is transparent and click through so basically it is an overlay displayed on normal windows.
Everything works fine so far... but only on a blank black canvas. Now if I try to hide the canvas, it hides everything in the window, including the cursor trail which I want to show.
`window.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "#000000")`

Instead, if i put the alpha value of the window to 0.0, it hides the entire window and all of its contents

`window.attributes("-alpha", 0.0)`

Here, I could not find any more answers, so can someone help me?